# Can I include the number twice in a Microsoft Word numbered list?

Tags: microsoft-word, list

Is it possible to include numbering twice in a Microsoft Word numbered list?

Example: I have the following list. I have  a spec to follow that I did not make and have no control over, so the list must be formatted with the number twice.

1. Item 1 (Apples)

   1.A Fruit

   1.B Seed
2. Item 2 (Cherries)

   2.A Fruit

   2.B Seed
3. Item 3 (Dill Pickles)

   3.A Fruit

   3.B Seed

Then my boss tells me to insert Bananas. The list then looks as follows:

1. Item 1 (Apples)

   1.A Fruit

   1.B Seed
2. Item 2 (Bananas)

   2.A Fruit

   2.B Seed
3. Item 2 (Cherries)

   3.A Fruit

   3.B Seed
4. Item 3 (Dill Pickles)

   4.A Fruit

   4.B Seed

Everything works as expected, but it's a pain for me to have to run through 27 numbered items and increment them all. Is there any way to generate the number in the numbering, twice? I would have my numbering template, then, be something like

"#.   Item #"

Is this possible?

Comment: Native Word? No. Numbered lists like you want must be done manually.  I do this for Board of Director meetings.  You would have to invent a Macro for this and that is not part of my skill set.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your username is "jsharpminor", are you comfortable with coding a Word macro in VisualBasic?

You can access the macro editor by:

1. On the Developer tab, in the Code group, click Macros.
2. In the Macro name box, type a name for the macro.
3. In the Macros in list, click the template or document in which you want to store the macro. (To make your macro available in all documents, be sure to click `Normal.dotm`.)
4. Click Create to open the Visual Basic Editor.

Then take a look at these code samples to see if you can cobble together a macro that simply looks at every list in your document, checks if it has the form `X. Item Y ([anything])` where `X =! Y`, and if so, update the `Y` so that it has the same value as `X`.

Finding and working with pagraphs in a list in a document

```vb
For Each mypara In ActiveDocument.Lists(2).ListParagraphs 
 mypara.Range.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble 
Next mypara
' source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.list.listparagraphs
```

Transforming a `Paragraph` object into a `Selection` object:

```vb
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
' source: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/how-to-select-a-paragraph-via-vba.1864077/
```

Reading and writing the text of a selection:

```vb
MsgBox Selection.Text
For i = 1 To 10 
 Selection.Text = "Line" & Str(i) & Chr(13) 
Next i
' source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.text
```

Answer (score 1):

### Consider using a [Sequence Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be) for your second number (the one following the description.

> The Seq (Sequence) field sequentially numbers chapters, tables,
> figures, and other items in a document. If you add, delete, or move an
> item and its respective Seq field, you can update remaining Seq fields
> in the document to reflect the new sequence.

- - 

> **Instructions**

> Identifier
>
> The name you assign to a series of items to number. The name must
> start with a letter and is limited to 40 characters (letters, numbers,
> and underscores). For example, the name for a series of tables might
> be "tables."

- - 

> **Switches**
>
> \c
>
> Repeats the closest preceding sequence number. This is useful for
> inserting chapter numbers in headers or footers.

> \h
>
> Hides the field result. Use it to refer to a Seq field in a
> cross-reference without printing the number. For example, you might
> want to refer to a numbered chapter but not print the chapter number.
> The \h switch doesn't hide the field result if a Format (*) switch is
> also present.

> \n
>
> Inserts the next sequence number for the specified items. This is the
> default.

> **\r n**
>
> Resets the sequence number to the specified number n. For example, {
> SEQ figure \r 3 } starts figure numbering at 3.

> \s
>
> Resets the sequence number at the heading level following the "s". For
> example, { SEQ figure \s 2 } starts numbering at the Heading 2 style.

So, you are using multi-level list numbering for the beginning numbers and Sequence fields for the ones that come at the end. When you want to restart the number, you use the `\r` switch to set it at the number you want to restart at.

You can save a Sequence field as an AutoText or Quick Parts entry to make it easy to insert multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StyleRef` like this:

1. Go to `Insert` tab.
2. In `Quick Parts`, click on `Field...`.
3. Choose `StyleRef` as field name.
4. Choose `List Paragraph` as field property.
5. Check the mark which says `Insert paragraph # in relative context`.
6. Click OK.

Please refer to the following image for the above-mentioned steps.

[image: Steps 1-6]

Once done, then:

1. Copy and paste that "1" after every item, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Yvk.png).
2. Select all by pressing `ctrl+A`.
3. Update the fields by pressing `F9`.

Now whenever you add an item (say, Banana) inside the list, just copy and paste "1" after that item, then update all the numbers by pressing `ctrl+A` followed by an `F9`.

Answer (score 0):

If the number in the text is always equal to the list number (i.e. **X. Item X**), you can use a cross reference to insert the number:

- Start a numbered list and type *Item*
- On the References tab, click *Cross reference* (Alt+L, E)
- Select Reference type: *Numbered Item*, and Reference to: *Paragraph
  number*
- Select the current item form the list, and click *Insert*

To update all numbers, select the entire list (or just the entire document: Ctrl+A) and then press F9 (or right click and then select *Update Field*)

Note: My version of Word is not in English, so names of menus may not be correctly translated.